# Calculating events that lead up to another event using Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Hi everyone and I new to complex SQL and to Clickhouse both. So sorry if this seems like a simple question, but I still can't figure it out.

Challenge:
I want to build an event path that leads to a specific event.

You probably have seen these types of analysis in Google Analytics, for instance:

[image: Reverse Path Analysis]

Basically, based on a target "end event", I am looking to build the path taken by the user to arrive at that event.

Suppose I have a table like this:

- date
- event_name (purchase, add_to_cart, search, browse)
- user_id

Now, given the final event, let's say "purchase", I want to understand what are the common paths for users to arrive at that event, just like the picture above.

How would you go about accomplishing that?

I am using Clickhouse for this analysis.

Thanks